# Stop firing didSet to avoid infinite recursion with didSet in Swift with multiple properties

Tags: swift, recursion, syntax, infinite, didset

I have a class with two properties whose value is set using didSet.

```
class MyClass {
    var myProp1: Bool {
        didSet {
            self.myProp2 += blinks ? 1 : -1
        }
    }
    var myProp2: Int {
        didSet {
            self.myProp1 = (midi % 2) != 0
        }
    }
}
```

This will result – as expected – in infinite recursion (myProp1 calling myProp2 calling myProp1...).

Is it possible to "turn off" the didSet behaviour when a property is called in another didSet? I know that didSet doesn't fire in init() and this should be similar.

I know about get/set and I know about the way to create a method, but I'm asking about suppressing didSet behaviour causing infinite recursion.

Comment: Add 2 bool properties to handle the face that one property was set and its didSet should do nothing.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to disable a call to `didSet`. In a case where you have two properties where setting one should update the other, you need a temporary property to be able to tell the other `didSet` not to do anything when being called indirectly through the first `didSet`.

Here's one working solution using a private `Bool` and some extra checks (I renamed the properties to match what you had in the `didSet` blocks to make a working example):

```swift
class MyClass {
    var blinks: Bool {
        didSet {
            if !avoidLoop {
                avoidLoop = true
                self.midi += blinks ? 1 : -1
                avoidLoop = false
            }
        }
    }
    var midi: Int {
        didSet {
            if !avoidLoop {
                avoidLoop = true
                self.blinks = (midi % 2) != 0
                avoidLoop = false
            }
        }
    }

    // Added so the code can be tested
    init() {
        blinks = false
        midi = 0
    }

    private var avoidLoop = false
}
```

Here's some sample code that runs without any problems with infinite recursion:

```swift
var xxx = MyClass()
print(xxx.blinks, xxx.midi)
xxx.blinks = true
print(xxx.blinks, xxx.midi)
xxx.midi = 6
print(xxx.blinks, xxx.midi)
```

Output:

> false 0
> true 1
> false 6

Comment: This is realllllly fragile. I'd really suggest exploring alternative designs

Comment: @Alexander I'm open to other ideas. But this solution does work. I'm not sure what's fragile about it. There may be steps needed to handle property updates from multiple threads but otherwise it gets the job done. Depending on the OP's needs, it is likely better to eliminate the needs for such code but the OP hasn't provided enough info to offer other designs.

Comment: Apart from the thread-safety concerns (which were there before anyway), this is fragile because it's easy to accidentally make changes that don't set the `avoidLoop`  value correctly. It also doesn't scale to a third variable very well, either. I'll think on it and see what I can come up with. "OP hasn't provided enough info to offer other designs." indeed

Comment: @Alexander So by your definition, my answer is *not* fragile since it is correctly setting `avoidLoop` and it doesn't need to deal with a 3rd property. But you are correct if someone tries to adapt this solution to more properties. There is room for programmer error to make a mistake. Of course that's true of just about any answer that someone tries to adapt to a different scenario. :)

Comment: I think my point is that this approach has so many "fiddly bits" (a correctly placed `if`, remembering to negate `avoidLoop`, remembering to set it before and after, not mixing up `= true` and `= false`, etc.) that lead to it being more fragile when being adapted to other scenarios. IMO a good solution (and I'm not counting my answer as one) here would correctly capture this mutually exclusive logic in a more structured/packaged way that's harder to mess up

Comment: Having all the mentioned concerns in mind, I accept this answer, because it does exactly answer my question: it says that didSet cannot be turned off per se and provides workaround embracing this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The given example problem is too abstract and mysterious to give a good alternative solution. Perhaps the best solution to your real underlying problem doesn't even involve property observers, but there's no way to know without more detail.

One way to prevent this recursion is to split your public APIs from some backing properties. The public computed properties here only update the private stored properties, but never each other, so there's no recursion.

```swift
class MyClass {
    let blinks = false
    let midi = 1
    
    public var myProp1: Bool {
        get { _myProp1 }
        set {
            self._myProp1 = myProp1
            self._myProp2 += blinks ? 1 : -1 // no recursion here
        }
    }
    public var myProp2: Int {
        get { _myProp2 }
        set {
            self._myProp1 = !midi.isMultiple(of: 2) // no recursion here
            self._myProp2 = myProp2
        }
    }
    
    private var _myProp1: Bool
    private var _myProp2: Int
}
```

I strongly suspect that the best approach here would involve splitting `myProp1` and `myProp2` into a new struct, and updating it as a whole on every mutation.